# how to implement dynamic in app purchase for ios

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I've developed an application with in-app purchase functionality. And for that, I used the in_app_purchase package.
App has more than one product want to generate dynamic product ID without doing manually .

Comment: This question is kind of vague, try adding examples of what you have tried and current code

Answer (score 0):

Its currently Impossible to add dynamic products to purchase. Each product has to be added in dashboard and reviewed before it can be used in the app. For multiple price product purchase you can use some third party payment gateway that supports Apple Pay. For example Razor pay or stripe

https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/stripe

If you wish to use only the IAP then you may have to set products at different prices for example

product 1 - 0.99

product 2 - 1.99

product 3 - 2.99 and so on

and use that for different products. That will be an exhaustive list of product pricing.

Comment: I already have implemented the razor pay in the app but the app rejected the review saying that the app should use in-app purchases.

Comment: Please appeal for a re-review informing about the razor pay and Apple Pay that you provide and the products are dynamically priced. If you are selling digital content then it has to be through IAP. can you give us more insights on the product please?

Comment: Digital training content 
it has two types 
1. live session 
2. record content of the same product

Comment: Ok so why dynamic price for the same please? Isnt it just 2 prices?

Comment: but I have multiple products id and prices may differ also depending on the content

Comment: Got it. Then you may appeal for a review again